# Angles between vectors using a non-standard inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

What is the angle between $\vec{x}=\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$ and $\vec{y}=\begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$ using the inner product defined as $⟨\vec{x},\vec{y}⟩=\vec{x}^{T}\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\vec{y}$

#### My Attempt

$$\Rightarrow ⟨\vec{x},\vec{y}⟩ = \begin{Vmatrix} \vec{x} \end{Vmatrix}\begin{Vmatrix} \vec{y} \end{Vmatrix} \cos \theta$$
$$\Rightarrow \cos \theta = \frac{⟨\vec{x},\vec{y}⟩}{\begin{Vmatrix} \vec{x} \end{Vmatrix}\begin{Vmatrix} \vec{y} \end{Vmatrix}}$$
$$\Rightarrow \cos \theta = \frac{\vec{x}^{T}\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\vec{y}}{\begin{Vmatrix} \vec{x} \end{Vmatrix}\begin{Vmatrix} \vec{y} \end{Vmatrix}}$$
$$\Rightarrow \cos \theta = \frac{{\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}}^{T}\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}}{\begin{Vmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{Vmatrix}\begin{Vmatrix}  -1 \\ 1  \end{Vmatrix}}$$
$$\cos \theta = \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2}}$$
$$\theta = cos^{-1}-\frac{1}{2} \approx 2.09 radian \approx 120 degree$$

But the accepted answer is **1.9**

What am I missing?

**Note** The question is from the  Week-2 Coursera Course `Mathematics for Machine Learning: PCA` video `Inner product: angles and orthogonality`

Comment: You need to take the norms using the one induced by the inner product.

Comment: @copper.hat Can you please elaborate?

Comment: In other words, $$\cos \theta = \frac{\langle x,y\rangle}{\sqrt{\langle x,x\rangle \langle y,y\rangle}}$$

Comment: @copper.hat Damm me :-) Thank you. I am mixing up concepts.

Comment: @copper.hat $\sqrt{\langle x,x\rangle}=\sqrt{1\cdot2\cdot 1+1\cdot1}=\sqrt 3$

Comment: @Andrei: Thanks for catching that, I will delete & add a corrected version.

Comment: $\|\binom{1}{1}\| =\sqrt{2+1} = \sqrt{3}$. $\|x\| = \sqrt{\langle x, x \rangle}$. (Thanks @Andrei.)